# Why am I getting an empty array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I am working on a product feedback app (with react) for my portfolio and came across an unexpected problem. The issue takes place in my SuggestionDetails component where I am getting the current id with useParams and filtering out the current product based on that id. Everything works and renders perfectly fine with the pre-existing suggestions array, but the problem starts when I try to render a new suggestion that I have created and added to the array.

**This is how I am getting the current suggestion:**

```
// I am getting the suggestions array through props

const { id } = useParams();

const [suggestion, setSuggestion] = useState(() => {
  const currentSuggestion =
    suggestions &&
    suggestions.filter((suggestion) =>
      suggestion.id === parseInt(id) ? suggestion : null
    );
  return currentSuggestion;
});
```

This is what the return value of the current suggestion should be (the new suggestion is still not created here):

[image: Expected result]

Here when I try to filted out the new suggestion (the last element) I get an empty array:

[image: Unexprected result]

I am still kind of new to this stuff and dont understand why this is happening. I have not added the code where I am creating a new suggestion and adding it to the current state, but I don't think the issue is there since it has clearly been created and added to current list of suggestion requests.
 
  **Any information on this would be greatly appreciated, thank you.**

Comment: Can you update your question to include a more complete and comprehensive code example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example It seems that your logic in the lazy state initializer returns either an array or null. Does you render logic account for potential null accesses?

Comment: Can `suggestions` have more than one match? If no, you probably should be using find() and not filter.

Comment: I'd use `const [suggestion, setSuggestion] = useState(null);` then use a `useEffect` callback to update the suggestion based on suggestions and id.

Comment: suggestions.filter expects only a predicate to check, and it returns null or an array of items that meet the predicate, so happy path is: `const suggestion = suggestions.filter(suggestion => suggestion.id === myId)[0]`. I would suggest to use suggestions.find instead

Comment: @mtx not 100% correct, it would still filter it out.

Comment: My guess is `id` is not what you think it is. Debug it `suggestions.filter((suggestion) => { console.log(suggestion.id, id, parseInt(id), suggestion.id === parseInt(id));
      return suggestion.id === parseInt(id); });`

Comment: @epascarello you are right

Comment: In your "expected" image the last element in the array appears to have an `id` property generated by `Math.random`, and you are parsing the `id` param to an integer, so it can't ever be equal. Maybe try `parseFloat` instead.... or don't use `Math.random` to generate GUIDs?

Comment: Were are you generating/adding new suggestions?

Comment: @DrewReese omg you are right. I will keep that in mind when using Math.random. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using `parseInt` instead of `parseFloat` to parse the id generated by `Math.random()`